# SharePoint threshold limit Not working for indexed Columns

Tags: rest, query, limitations, threshold

I am Facing A issue with SharePoint Rest Query 
Requestype Column is indexed , single Line of text , Has Three types of only 
(Values and Count)

- Credit- 3787
- One Off - 13019
- Reccuring - 6202

I am Trying to retrieve only Credit type but it is failing and giving threshold error.
I need to retrieve all credit requests 
Query :
https://yy.xx.com/sites/xxxxy/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('XYZ')/Items?$select=ID&$filter= ( RequestType eq 'Credit' )

Thanks For helping me solve the issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. The RequestType column is indexed? And has only one of those three values? But you're filtering on "Credit" (which isn't one of those values?) Can you maybe clean up the question a little bit and provide clearer details?

Comment: I need to retrieve all credit requests, the rest is filling even though the column is indexed and returned item is less than 5000

Comment: Can you add more context of the error you are getting. Also, using REST API in SP, you can get 100 items max in one call, and when using Search REST API, you get 500 max items. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: Was the index created before the total list went over 5,000? If it wasn't then the index probably isn't actually working. Can you create a view and filter on just the RequestType eq 'Credit'? I've never used this when the count for one of the values is under the threshold, but the others are over the threshold. That might be part of the problem.